# AJAX injected PartialView apply Jquery ( ASP.NET AJAX JQUERY HTML)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, html

If anyone can help me with this it would be awesome.
I'm creating a web app that uses AJAX to inject a partial view into my my main page. 
I'm using jquery .accoridon to be able to toggle these AJAX loaded views(div) when they are in the main view. However, this is not working. Prior to using AJAX the accordion was working fine.

I have tried using the .on .live .delegate to the jquery function but, still no luck.

Below is the section the section of my page where content is to be loaded into the accordion

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").delegate.accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
  </script>
<div id="accordion">
        <div id="replace2">            
        <div id="replace1">
            <!-- This is where content is loaded too via ajax, it's needed so the #accordian  div is not      reaplced --> 
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The next part is an example of how im adding my first bit of ajax content

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New",
    "create_new", new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId="replace1",
    InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
```

and this is how im updating my second bit of ajax content

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Create New",
    "create_new", new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId="replace2",
    InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
```

Does anybody have anythoughts how I can load this content into  a workign jquery accordion?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Did you checked Chrome/Firebug console for JavaScript error? Take a look at Network tab as well to see if you are sending a request and receive some response.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response. 
However, there appears to be no JS errors.
Network shows requests being made without any issues.

Comment: Are you loading the contents of the accordion dynamically using this approach?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.